# How to add a timer to c# Web Application in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer

I have a very basic web page built intro page, press start button opens main page, press finish button openings thank you page

I need to insert a timer so that it starts when the user presses the start button on the intro page
and stops when they press the finish button on the main page.

Comment: Why are people so afraid of documentation?  [MSDN has perfectly good examples on how to do this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yup @EvanL i think he wants the Stopwatch class. Look at my answer.

Comment: That's not how web pages work. You can not have a timer run on the server while "the page is in the browser". Imaging 10000 people accessing your page at once - would you then have 10000 timers? If you develop a web application, stop thinking in desktop application terms.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a session variable to store the DateTime.Now value in the intro page and then check the time difference at a later time. That is the most easy thing I think of. Not the most good looking, but the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, more information [MDSN: DateTime.Now Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So eventually you always can find difference between current and launched time.